# Routing between subnets in a Linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I have two Debian Linux Virtual Machines with two virtual adapters each, both adapters are on separate subnets. I need two subnets to test security tools

```
Subnet 1 - 192.168.50.x
Subnet 2 - 192.168.70.x
```

I need the two subnets to be able to communicate with each other but I have only very basic Linux.

Is it possible to route the information between the two subnets?

Comment: Yes, but you are asking for a lesson about fundamentals of TCP/IP networking. For example here is a short explanation: [Basic IP Routing](http://www.sangoma.com/tutorials/tcp_ip/basic-ip-routing/) or beginning of this book looks suitable: [TCP/IP Tutorial and Technical Overview](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/gg243376.html). In your case any of the two machines (or both) can be configured as a router. The other machines in the two subnets must be configured accordingly to use the one of the two machines as a router.

Comment: I understand how routing work but I needed an answer on how I can configure Linux to do this, I have found the answer.

Comment: The question did not look so at all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment out `#sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: This command enables IP packet forwarding which is a necessary condition for routing. `/etc/sysctl.conf` should contain only *variable=value* part not the `sysctl -w` command. The command can be executed directly from a shell for an immediate change.